# Java Stopwatch that updates the GUI every second?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, stopwatch

I'm a Java beginner and I'm trying to build a simple stopwatch program that displays the time on a swing GUI. Making the stopwatch is easy, however I cannot find a way to make the GUI update every second and display the current time on the stopwatch. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `Swing`'s `Timer` class. More on the way of using the `Timer` is available, for example, [in the question and particularly answers to it.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11053097/613495)

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5529043/230513).

Comment: Yea I know I had it somewhere [one of my answers related to use of `Timer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5911514/613495). @trashgod very nice answer/sample +1 here and +1 there... and I am out of votes ... for today :)

Comment: @trashgod Just had a look to your answer, it looks far more better then mine. I will just delete my answer below :)

Comment: Please have a glance at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907583/set-dynamic-jlabel-text-in-a-jdialog-by-timer/9908342#9908342) code too :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines should do it:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058263/230513 */
public class Clock {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel(" ", JLabel.CENTER);

    public Clock() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Seconds");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(timeLabel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        timer.schedule(new UpdateUITask(), 0, 1000);
    }

    private class UpdateUITask extends TimerTask {

        int nSeconds = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(nSeconds++));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Clock clock = new Clock();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `timeLabel` will always display the number of seconds the timer has been running.

1. You will need to correctly format it to display "hh:mm:ss"; one approach is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705674/230513).
2. Create a container and add the label to it so that you can display it as part of the GUI.
3. Compare the result to this [alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5529043/230513) using `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: I made the GUI using the visual editor from netbeans, how can I reference a jlabel inside the GUI?

Comment: @trashgod which part needs an invokeLater?

Comment: @GETah The `run()` method of `UpdateUITask`, since a java.util.Timer will run it off the EDT.

Comment: (Also, a `ScheduleExecutorService` would probably the more modern equivalent to a `java.util.Timer` to begin with, if only to use the same API anywhere you need to have background tasks running.)

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for the updates ;) +1 for you answer on the other related question  ;)