# Multithreading program not working

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am trying to make this work. I create a window, with one text field and button, then I run the **run()** method which should refresh text in textfield, and when I click on button it should iterate number by 1. I want to make this work simultaneously but I am stuck. It just iterates the number but do not refresh a value in textfield.Could you please help me somehow? I thought its easy  to learn about Threads but...no :-D Here is the code.

#### Window class

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial") 
public class Okno extends JFrame implements ActionListener,Runnable {

    private JFrame o = new JFrame();
private static JTextField t = new JTextField();
private JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
private static int x = 0;
protected JButton b = new JButton("KLIK");


Okno() {

    o.setVisible(true);
    o.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
    o.setLayout(null);
    o.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    t.setBounds(10, 10, 60, 20);
    t2.setBounds(80, 10, 60, 20);
    b.setBounds(50, 80, 60, 30);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            while (true) {
                Okno.work();
                System.out.println("Klik");
            }

        }
    });
    o.add(t);
    o.add(b);
    o.add(t2);
}
public static int iter(){

    x++;
    return x;
}

public static void work(){
    try {
        iter();
        System.out.println(x);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    t.setText(Integer.toString(x));
    System.out.println("RUN");
    }
}
    }
```

#### Main Class

```
public class ThreadDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
 Okno o = new Okno();

 while(true){
 o.run();
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Your code ignores Swing threading rules by trying to make Swing calls on a background thread and by calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing event thread. Either use a Swing Timer (as per an answer) or use a SwingWorker to be sure that Swing method calls are only made on the Swing event thread. There are tutorials that cover this which you should be able to find.

Comment: Thanks for advice Mr D! I am stuck with this for hours this may solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is single threaded. Calling `Thread.sleep` prevents UI updates. Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

From GETah's answer to [java stopwatch that updates gui every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058172/java-stopwatch-that-updates-the-gui-every-second):

> Something along these lines should do it:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058263/230513 */
public class Clock {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel(" ", JLabel.CENTER);

    public Clock() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Seconds");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(timeLabel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        timer.schedule(new UpdateUITask(), 0, 1000);
    }

    private class UpdateUITask extends TimerTask {

        int nSeconds = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(nSeconds++));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Clock clock = new Clock();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> The `timeLabel` will always display the number of seconds the timer
>   has been running.
>
> 1. You will need to correctly format it to display "hh:mm:ss"; one approach is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705674/230513).
> 2. Create a container and add the label to it so that you can display it as part of the GUI.
> 3. Compare the result to this [alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5529043/230513) using `javax.swing.Timer`.